# Create LMDB for new test data

Tags: caffe, lmdb

I have an LMDB train data file for the [VPGNet](https://github.com/SeokjuLee/VPGNet) CNN model pre- trained on Caltech Lane data set.

I would like to test it on new data set different from the training data set. How to create [LMDB](https://github.com/SeokjuLee/VPGNet/blob/master/caffe/models/vpgnet-novp/make_lmdb.sh) for the new test data.

Do I need to modify prototxt files for testing with pre-trained net. For testing do I need a [prototxt](http://hhttps://github.com/SeokjuLee/VPGNet/blob/master/caffe/models/vpgnet-novp/solver.prototxt) file or there is a specific command.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Lightning Memory-Mapped Databases (LMDB) formats can be efficiently process as input data.

We create the native format  (lmdb) for training and validating the model.

Once the trained model converged and the loss is calculated on training and validation data,

we use separate data (Unknown data/ Data which is not used for training) for inference the model.

In case if we are running a classification inference on a single image or set of images,

We need not convert those in to lmdb. Instead we can just run a forward pass on the stacked topology with the image/images converted into the desired format (numpy arrays).

For More info :

https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/training-and-deploying-deep-learning-networks-with-caffe-optimized-for-intel-architecture